# load ACTUAL data of SELECT query in chunks (without execution of same query again)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

Suppose, if I execute one select query (HQL) and it gives 100K rows as result. I would like to know if there is a way to load in java(or any other language) those 100k in 1K of chunks After query is finished executing.
The reason for me to break it in chunks is - I do not know where exactly those 100K results will be stored, while i perform processing on them in java. But i would like to use lesser memory consumption.

1. execute query(hibernate criteria with hql) (suppose 100K row results)
2. pick first 1K in them (***without loading other 99K in memory of JVM or somewhere, like lazy loading in hibernate***)
3. process
4. pick next 1K
5. repeat from (2)

***update- I do not want to hit the query again.***
either i am not able to understand any of the answers or you people aren't able to understand my question

Comment: There are some good references on the web, such as [this one](http://www.numerati.com/2012/06/26/reading-large-result-sets-with-hibernate-and-mysql/).

Comment: I believe you mean to say that, hit database with next counter each time i have need of result?

Comment: I meant to as if there is a way to hit query & then get pointers of results (primary keys). and using those pointers get next set of results(actual data).

Comment: Configure your connection to use [cursor based retrieval](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/query.html#query-with-cursor) then adjust the fetch size accordingly.

Comment: Try playing with `ScrollableResults` (but don't forget to also set `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` property since default pg driver behaviour is to download all results into memory) - it allows to process records one by one without fetching all of them at given time.

Answer (score 0):

First split up your query in two queries.

First one is get the count of the result set by changing the Select part to something like `SELECT COUNT(o) FROM Object o`.

Send is you existing query without changes.

Then first run the count query an request a single result. It will be directly a `Long` value with the result size.

Then calculate you iterations:

```
long pages = Math.ceil(count/1000);
```

Last but not least iterate over the calculated pages and fire up your query by setting Offset and Limit before getting the result.

Comment: `First split up your query in two queries.` But what will happen if the database changes in between the two queries?

Comment: That can also happen in the time where you work on the 100k records without paging ;)

Comment: Put all in wrapper method which calls him self recursivly till it find no changes in db any more

Comment: sorry, but i am not able to understand your answer. Can you be little more clear?

Comment: If you think the data changes in the time of processing your query result, regardless if paginated or directly got 100k records. Then you could run the method which does the database work in a seperate method which checks if database has changed after executing your job, if so the method calls it self again. This wil call it self until it finds no changes.